# Помогите разобраться со скриптом ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Не понимаю почему не срабатывает скрипт:

```
<?
  if(substr_count($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?AA')) $AA = @end(@explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));  
?>
<script>
var AA = '<? echo $AA; ?>';
if( AA) {

    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $('#query_user').submit(function(){  
            $.ajax({  
                type: "POST",  
                url: "cabinet/confirm_registration.php",  
                data: "AA="+AA, 
                success: function(html){  
                    $("#window_data").html(html);
                }  
            });  
            return false;  
        });  
    });

}
</script>
```

Скрипт должен отправлять POST запрос на скрипт myscript.php, и полученные данные из myscript.php (html код) должен вставлять в `div` с id `window_data`.

Comment: Опишите конкретно "что не работает". Что вы ожидаете, а что получаете. Какая ошибка происходит. Какие данные вам возвращает `myscript .php`. Кстати, вы неправильно вызываете функцию. Посмотрите синтаксис [здесь](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Во первых, когда должен запускаться скрипт? Во вторых это что `data: "&AA="+AA,`?

Comment: Я дополнил предыдущий комментарий. Обратите внимание на то как вы вызываете функцию. Она ожидает не список переменных `а, b, c, d`а объект `{}`. Посмотрите по ссылке в прошлом комментарии.

Comment: AA это переменная описана перед этим скриптов на js.

Comment: Запускаться должно в внутри функции js.

Comment: Просто никогда еще не работал с ajax, мне хотя бы рабочий пример.

Comment: Тогда где объявление функции и объявление переменной АА?

Comment: Выложил весь код

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
    $(document).ready(function(){ // Скрипт запускается после загрузки страницы
        var AA = "некий текст"; // объявляем переменную АА

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", // тип передачи данных
            url: "cabinet/confirm_registration.php", // адрес обработчика у вас "cabinet/confirm_registration.php"
            dataType: "html", // тип получаемых данных
            data: {AA: AA}, // вместе с аяксом передаем дополнительно данные переменной "АА", в cabinet/confirm_registration.php ее получаем как $AA = $_POST['AA']
            success: function(e){ // если запрос удачный
                $("#window_data").html(e); // вносим в блок с id="window_data" результат с cabinet/confirm_registration.php
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```